# Take bounciness out of horizontal accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, horizontal-accordion

http://vincent-massaro.com/map/

Here is an example I am working on of a horizontal accordion linked with a Google map. The problem I am having is when you click on a slice on the right side, and then click another slice while the previous one is open, the first slice bounces in place. Any way to remove the bouncing going on? Thanks!

Comment: You might say... "debouncing" :P

Comment: +1 fir the use of the word "bounciness"